# Are images loaded via JavaScript indexed by google?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if images loaded via JavaScript on my website will be indexed by Google images?

thanks

Comment: Not a SEO expert, but [We Tested How Googlebot Crawls Javascript And Here’s What We Learned](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) could be helpful.

Comment: @DominikSchreiber thanks .So if i understand (im french) google should index all the links i use in my external javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for me: 
just made an Image Sitemaps.
" Image sitemap information helps Google discover images we might not otherwise find (such as images your site reaches with JavaScript code), and allows you to indicate to Google images on your site that you want Google to crawl and index."

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636

edit: it doesn't work. all images submitted via the sitemap are not indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google can execute some JavaScript to find content but Google has limitations on what it can do, and what it can understand. The best practice remains the same: put the content you want Google to crawl and index in basic HTML. For example, use jQuery tabs to put the content on one file instead of AJAX tabs that spreads out the content across several files. In short, make it easy for Google to access your content.

Comment: thanks.  But for pictures and videos... Should i put all the links in my html files? If have different arrays with the urls in an external .js files, will google not index them? sorry for my english

Comment: i made an image sitemap.